# Nginx-rtmp vod play a list of files from a directory

Tags: nginx, video, ffmpeg, mp4, rtmp

I have the following use case:

I would like to playback MP4 files one after another in a mounted directory with nginx-rtmp. I managed to play/access only 1 files at a time.

So instead of this
rtsp://192.168.1.100/vod/movie01.MP4

then change it to this manually
rtsp://192.168.1.100/vod/movie02.MP4

Have and endpoint like this and play all of the videos one after another (without using ffmpeg stream to nginx rtmp endpoint).

rtsp://192.168.1.100/vod/stream

I have a simple config so far

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        # video on demand for mp4 files
        application vod {
          allow play all;
          wait_video on;
          play /opt/video/vod;

    }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can push to your nginx-rtmp server with ffmpeg with ffmpeg you can use multiple inputs so your server will serve them all one after another